# even after sanitizing, it shows not allowed to load local resources- Angular 7

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular7

Even after sanitizing the image resource url, still doesn't render images gives me error Not allowed to load local resource:

```
file:///D:/Projects/Test/Test/Images/pant.jpg
```

Here is my api:

```
[{"productName":"phone","imagePath":"D:/Projects/Test/Test/Images/pant.jpg"},
 {"productName":"pant","imagePath":"D:/Projects/Test/Test/Images/phone.jpg"}]
```

Comment: Which part of t he message you don't understand? If every java script could read all files form the file system, no one would be using browser these days, as it would be trivially easy to steal peoples data and sensitive files

Comment: Yes, but which part of the message is unclear? You can't read local files form an untrusted environment (such as the internet zone), that would be a **serious security problem**. Your images must be served from a webserver.

Comment: actually i was retrieving a list of images from .net core api as response json above. And when i use the reseponse image url in my <img> then it shows error Not allowed to load local resource.

Comment: Please read the comment and understand whats written there, then you'll realize why its not possible. You must send urls to a remote server, not to local files. Just repeating yourself won't solve your problem. This mechanism is there to protect the security of the browser users and you can't get around it. And the visitors of your site wont have this files on their hard drive. You must serve them from **your server** (via http url, not local file)

Comment: the problem was with the web api that it was returning static file location instead of actual server url.

Comment: Then change it. We have no idea how your api works, saves the file or under which url they are available. You know the source, not we. Your images must be reachable via web in order for it to work (http://...  urls)